# Calculation of Water Temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

In a close looped process the soft water (approx. $200\frac{m^3}{h}$ at $14$ barg) gets heated gradually from the ambient temperature to $\Delta$T of 20°C in $13-14$ minutes, i.e. if amb. temp is 45°C then outlet temperature is 65°C. After 13-14 minutes of operation the temperature slowly falls down to less than the ambient temperature for the next 25 minutes. And the process is again continued.

The cooling is effected by passing the hot water through a heat exchanger. The secondary cooling water is sent back to the cooling tower and then again recirculated back.Since I have chilled water at around 10°C in my plant, I want utilize this for cooling the soft water by dipping the pipe into a chilled water Tank and allowing a rise of $\Delta$T of 5°C in the chilled water tank which can be pumped back to the chiller plant.

This way I can save lot of investment and maintenance cost for cooling tower and heat exchangers. Am I right in my thinking and if so then how do I calculate the transient heat transfer?

Comment: Please make a little bit clearer, what is your question.